# Jqplot not displaying chart

Tags: jsp, jqplot

My jsp does not seem to be running jqplot at all.

Here is my code:

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="${scriptRoot}/excanvas/excanvas.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><![endif]-->

<script src="${scriptRoot}/jquery/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="${scriptRoot}/jquery/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.highlighter.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="${scriptRoot}/jquery/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.cursor.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="${scriptRoot}/jquery/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="${scriptRoot}/jquery/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="${scriptRoot}/jquery/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="${scriptRoot}/jquery/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="${cssRoot}/jquery/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div id="chartdiv1" style="width:1000px;height:300px"></div>
<br><br />
Welcome 
<script type="text/javascript">

$ (document).ready(function(){
  var plot1 = $.jqplot ('chart1', [[1,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]]);
});

</script>
```

I have ensured I have the required CSS and Scripts files and folders in the required folder structure.
Can someone please help me out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter to the `$.jqplot` function is a div id.  So I imagine you're missing something like

```
<div id="chart1" style="height:300px; width:500px;"></div>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be it, for some reason StackOverflow had hidden that div part from my code.

Comment: @Rakesh Sharma, Now that you have it visible I see that the names don't match. You had the div id as `chartdiv1` but the function is using `chart1`.

Comment: That was it ! Took 4 days to debug this.. Thank You So Very Much @developerwjk